# DST broke bash script, how to set local time for variable?

Tags: bash, shell, centos

I have a few simple scripts that generate and send/assess SOAP requests to a number of web services, essentially they submit a sample request to ensure the web service is up, and acting as expected.

They are used as status checks for my client.

So DST just changed the other day, and because the time bash is in is UTC and I am in BST/GMT, the scripts stopped working, I've tried everything I can think of (export TZ=":Europe/Dublin" etc..etc.. ) with no joy.

Do you know how I could change the "ctime" variable to produce the local time?

```
#!/bin/bash

#//Get parameters
ENV="$1"
ENV2="$2"

checkdir="/opt/local/c/c/c/"

#//Generate nonce and hashed password
nonce=$(echo "$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM")
hashnonce=$(echo $nonce | base64)
passwd="tiger"
ctime=`echo $(date +'%s')`
etime=`echo "$ctime+600" | bc`
timestamp=`echo $(date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $ctime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')`
timecreate=`echo $(date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $ctime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`
timeexpire=`echo $(date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $etime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`
combined=`echo -e "$nonce\n$timestamp$passwd"`
hashpass=$(echo -n "$combined" | openssl sha1 -binary | base64)

#//Output generated XML to file
echo -e '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sear="http://www.x.com/c/c/c">
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-20"><wsu:Created>'$timecreate'</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>'$timeexpire'</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-19"><wsse:Username>scott</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'$hashpass'</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'$hashnonce'</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>'$timestamp'</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<sear:searchRequest>
<sear:importantNumber>'$ENV2'</sear:importantNumber>
<sear:status>R</sear:status>
<sear:versionNumber>1.0</sear:versionNumber>
</sear:searchRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' > $checkdir/Request_$ENV.xml

#//Send soap request and output to text file
curl -s --header "content-type: application/soap+xml" --data @$checkdir/Request_$ENV.xml https://$ENV.x.com:443/c/c/c/c/ > $checkdir/Result_$ENV.txt

#//Grep for response
echo `grep "Complete" $checkdir/Result_$ENV.txt | wc -l`

exit;
```

Comment: Ouch, just learned how to write this stuff a couple of months ago, wasn't sure how else to format it.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. As is, your `ctime` variable contains the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, UTC. This is DST and TZ agnostic. What are you looking for exactly? Besides, your script is such a mess that it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BenCoughlan: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/ to get some hints to your code style. But this does not solve your problem.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf those variables are echoed into the xml, which is sent off as a soap UI request, the reason why there are so many of them is due to the strict validation on the server's side. for ctime, I would like to know how to render it in BST, if possible, and if I need to change from the # of seconds since 1970-00-00... then how I would format them the same?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution. I have removed all useless `echo` as well as backquotes. The solution of your problem was simply to give `TZ` to `date`, see below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get parameters
if (($# != 2)); then
    echo "USAGE: $0 arg1 arg2" >&2    # Specify what parameters you need
    exit 1
fi
ENV="$1"
ENV2="$2"

# Configuration
MYTZ="Europe/Dublin"
checkdir="/opt/local/c/c/c/"

# Generate nonce and hashed password
nonce="$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"
hashnonce=$(echo $nonce | base64)
passwd="tiger"
ctime=$(TZ="$MYTZ" date +'%s')
etime=$(echo "$ctime+600" | bc)
timestamp=$(TZ="$MYTZ" date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $ctime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')
timecreate=$(TZ="$MYTZ" date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $ctime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
timeexpire=$(TZ="$MYTZ" date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $etime seconds" +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
combined=$(echo -e "$nonce\n$timestamp$passwd")
hashpass=$(echo -n "$combined" | openssl sha1 -binary | base64)

# Output generated XML to file
cat > "$checkdir/Request_$ENV.xml" << ENDOFTEXT
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sear="http://www.x.com/c/c/c">
<soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-20"><wsu:Created>'$timecreate'</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>'$timeexpire'</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-19"><wsse:Username>scott</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'$hashpass'</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'$hashnonce'</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>'$timestamp'</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<sear:searchRequest>
<sear:importantNumber>'$ENV2'</sear:importantNumber>
<sear:status>R</sear:status>
<sear:versionNumber>1.0</sear:versionNumber>
</sear:searchRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
ENDOFTEXT

# Send soap request and output to text file
curl -s --header "content-type: application/soap+xml" --data "@$checkdir/Request_$ENV.xml" https://$ENV.x.com:443/c/c/c/c/ > "$checkdir/Result_$ENV.txt"

# Grep for response
grep "Complete" $checkdir/Result_$ENV.txt | wc -l

exit
```

Comment: You still need to remove some single quotes in the heredoc of `cat`. `echo $nonce | base64` will include the trailing newline; I'm not sure the OP wants this (or even is aware of this); `printf '%s' "$nonce" | base64` seems preferable. `date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 $ctime seconds"` looks retarded compared to `date -d "@$ctime"`, but maybe centos's `date` doesn't handle this. `combined=$nonce$'\n'$timestamps$passwd` would look better. `echo -n` is better written with a `printf`. `nonce="$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM"` is really, really ugly. You shouldn't use that. There still are a few quotes missing.

Comment: `etime=$(echo "$ctime+600" | bc)` should be written as `((etime=ctime+600))`. `bc` is useless here (no date overflows showing up anytime soon).

Comment: I'm agree with all your comments, I didn't read all the details.

Comment: Thanks @EdouardThiel, for your input, but this doesn't change the timestamp, as Gniourf stated, this is a count of seconds since the UNIX epoch, so it won't render in different time zones/for DST in any area.

Answer (score 0):

So the following worked for me.

```
#Decide if it's winter or summer time, alter var ctime accordingly
ctime=$(date +%s)
if perl -e 'exit ((localtime)[8])' ; then
    ((ctime+=3600))
fi
```

I know the code was pretty messy, thanks for the tips guys, went back to running Perl from within the script, not ideal, but it works :) - much good karma to you all :)

Comment: I've edited your script; it should be more efficient.